# why else statement cannot run in loop for C?

Tags: c, for-loop, c-strings, palindrome, function-definition

Here is the code and when I run it, the statements show that the loop cannot jump into else function. I am not sure which part of code is wrong.

```
bool isPalindrome(char A[], int n) {

    int flag = 1;
    int i;
    
    for (i = 0; i <= strlen(A); i++) {
        if (A[i] != A[strlen(A) - i - 1]) {
            flag = 0;
            break;
        } else {
            flag = 1;
        }
    
    return flag;
}

int main(void) {
    
    char A[] = {};
    bool result;

    printf("Enter a word:");
    scanf("%c", A);
    
    result = isPalindrome(A, strlen(A));

    if (result == true) {
        printf("yes");
    } else {
        printf("no");
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

I hope someone can help me fix this problem.

Comment: There's a missing `}` to close the loop.

Comment: Remember that `i<=strlen(A)` will *include* the null-terminator. And that will make `strlen(A)-i-1` be equal to `-1` which is out of bounds and give you *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Lots of things in your code are wrong. You declare a zero length array; you use the wrong format specifier to read a string; you run the loop to include testing the terminating `nul` character ...

Comment: ... and the `else { flag = 1; }` is entirely redundant.

Comment: and don't call `strlen(A)` repeatedly in the loops like that. Store the result in a variable and reuse

Comment: Activate compiler warnings and read them

Answer (score 1):

Your program does not compile because there is a missing `}` in the `isPalindrome` function before the `return flag;` statement.

Furthermore, there is no need to set `flag` to `1` in the loop after each successful test.

Note also that since you are providing the string length as an argument, there is no need to compute `strlen(A)` multiple times.

Here is a simplified version:

```
bool isPalindrome(const char A[], int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (A[i] != A[n - i - 1])
            return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

The above function tests each character twice. You can further simplify it this way:

```
bool isPalindrome(const char A[], int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i <-- n; i++) {
        if (A[i] != A[n])
            return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

The main function is also incorrect:

- you should define the array with a specified length eg: `char A[100]`.
- you should use `%s` instead of `%c` to read the word, or better `%99s` to prevent a potential buffer overflow.

Here is a modified version:

```
int main(void) {
    char A[100];
    bool result;

    printf("Enter a word: ");
    if (scanf("%99s", A) != 1)
        return 1;
    
    result = isPalindrome(A, strlen(A));
    if (result == true) {
        printf("yes\n");
    } else {
        printf("no\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: if (scanf("%99s", A) != 1)
        return 1;   Can you explain this code ? I understand that array A only accept up to 99 characters but why the scanf function may not equal to 1 and return 1.

Answer (score 0):

This declaration

```
char A[]={};
```

is invalid in C. You may not use an empty braced list as an initializer.

In your program you should explicitly specify the size of the character array as for example

```
char A[100];
```

As you are trying to check whether a string is a palindrome then there is no sense to use the second parameter in the function declaration moreover when it is even not used

```
bool isPalindrome(char A[], int n){
```

The function should be declared like

```
bool isPalindrome( const char A[] );
```

and called like

```
bool result = isPalindrome( A );
```

Within the function the condition of the for loop

```
for(i=0; i<=strlen(A) ;i++){
```

is wrong.

Also calling the function `strlen` numerous times is inefficient.

```
if(A[i] != A[strlen(A)-i-1]){
```

The function can look the following way

```
bool isPalindrome( const char s[] )
{
    size_t n = strlen( s );
    size_t i = 0;

    while ( i < n / 2 && s[i] == s[n - i - 1] ) i++;

    return i == n / 2;
}
```

Comment: @klutt  It is not technically true. It is invalid according to the C and C++ standards. In C even if an array has explicitly the number of elements then you may not use an empty braced list. This can be changed when the C23 Standard will be accepted.

Comment: @klutt I do not know what standard you are referring.:) In the C Standard before the C23 Standard  in the grammar of list initialization there is written { initializer-list }. In the C23 Standard there is added { }. Moreover in C++ and C23 "An
array of unknown size shall not be initialized by an empty initializer."

Comment: My bad this time